# Marketing Cloud Enhanced FTP logs

Tags: marketing-cloud, logging, activityhistory

Does Enhanced FTP log IP addresses from users? I mean a history of IPs, logins.

Comment: If my answer helped, please mark it as accepted so others can easily see this has been solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

At least this data isn't available to the user/administrator. However I am sure the data is is being logged, but only accessible by Salesforce Marketing Cloud technical support staff. The "Activity" section of FTP account administration covers changes made to the configuration (e.g. the password, etc.) only.

So if you need any specific data you will have to create a support case in order to have someone retrieve the data for you. (*NOTE:* I guess this counts as developer support and therefore you need to be enrolled to the premier success plan)